# Seaborn stripplot better way to visually separate variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot, stripplot

What is a way to visually separate the variables in a Seaborn stripplot? (Using Seaborn v. 0.11.1)

For example,

```
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["species"])
sns.stripplot(data=dfm, x="species", y="value", hue="variable", dodge=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```

[image]

Is there a way to box-out the different species? My real dataset is busier and getting hard to read. I've increased the figure size, but I still want some sort of subtle visual separator.

Here's a sketch of generally what I am after (open to more visually appealing solutions):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a line, something like this might work for you. Line style can be changed

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["species"])
sns.stripplot(data=dfm, x="species", y="value", hue="variable", dodge=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

for x in range(0, len(dfm['species'].unique()) - 1):
  plt.plot([x + 0.5, x + 0.5], [0, dfm['value'].max()], c='black')
```

[image]

Something like this could also be good

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["species"])
sns.stripplot(data=dfm, x="species", y="value", hue="variable", dodge=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)

for x in range(0, len(dfm['species'].unique())):
    plt.axvspan(x - 0.5, x + 0.5, facecolor='black', alpha=[0.2 if x%2 == 0 else 0.1][0])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) variant of [`sns.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html): [`sns.catplot(kind='strip', ...)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).  This creates a separate subplot per species:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["species"])
g = sns.catplot(data=dfm, col="species", y="value", x="variable", hue="variable", kind='strip')
g.add_legend()
g.set(xlabel='') # remove the x labels
g.set(xticks=[]) # remove the xticks (these contain the same info as the legend)
```

[image: sns.catplot with kind='strip']